# Plugin implementation: How to call a method on an ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, plugins

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to create a *plugin* to use in a Rack *middleware*. This is the first time that I make this experience, so be patient if I write some of wrong.

What I need is to call a method *on* an ActiveRecord after run a `find` method. That is, I would like to do something like this:

```
@accounts = Account.find([1,2,3]).to_page
```

The method `to_page` should change some information in `@accounts` data without to change the object structure itself (e.g.: if the "original" `@accounts` is an array, it should remain an array).

At this time in my plugin folder I have the following files:

```
# init.rb
require 'sl_pagination'
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, SlPagination)


#sl_pagination.rb
module SlPagination
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def to_page
      # see below for more info
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    #none
  end
end
```

In the Rack middleware I have:

```
require 'sl_pagination'
...
```

---

If in the middleware I use `Account.find([1,2,3]).to_page` declaring

```
#sl_pagination.rb
def to_page
  return "Test_account_page"
end
```

it will work and I will retrieve the "Test_account_page" value as well, but I can't find a solution to change and return the ActiveRecord itself as wrote above. So, **how can I modify the ActiveRecord?**

I tryed to "play" on `self` and `return self` in the `to_page` method, but it seams don't work. I also thinked to use `acts_as_something` but I must still study and understand that (if you explain when using `acts_as`, it is a surplus! :-)). Furthermore, I don't know if the latter solution can help me to accomplish what I aim to do.

Comment: how do you need to modify the data?

Comment: I Guess you gave pagination as just an example and you are trying to do something more useful

Comment: @errorhandler I have to build an hash and add in that the ActiveRecord values and some other information.

Comment: I had this question in my gem and I extended the Array class to get what I expected

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into `ActiveRecord::Relation` to extend AR and behave like other AR features. You can find more details about `ActiveRecord::Relation` in http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough.